# Images are not displayed in browsers

Tags: html, css, image, path

I have created a basic web page with html and css and I have included some images, and although they are displayed locally, not with the browsers.I don't want to use absolute paths.Why is this happening?I've tried to used different routes such as:

```
<img src="images/research.png" alt="img">
```

```
<img src="../l22.github.io/images/stats.png" alt="img">
```

My folds are desktop-->website-->l22(index.html,style.css and another fold called images with the images that i have been using)

I also tried to use absolute paths,not working,and as a last minute option using the image link from unsplash directly in the source and this doesn't work too.

Comment: The first line you wrote should work if your `index.html` and your `images` folder ar in the same parent folder. Please be sure `research.png` is in the `images` folder.

Comment: Yes it is,but it still doesn't work.Any other ideas??

Comment: I understand you don't want to use full urls, but what happens if you do that just as a test? Are the image appearing?

Comment: I did it,still not working.this is the  very first time this has happened to me.I don't know what to do.

Answer (score 0):

So, at first with hyperlinks didn't seem to work,but after some 'git push' the images are  now displaying in the webpage.Still don't know what happened.I would try to fix it to use relative paths, as always.Thak you all 4 your help!!:D